# Implicitly declared copy-constructor for classes without data-members and base-classes

Tags: c++, constructor

The Standarad `N3797::12.8/8  [class.copy]` says:

> The implicitly-declared copy constructor for a class X will have the
>   form X::X(const X&) if
>
> — each direct or virtual base class B of X has
>   a copy constructor whose first parameter is of type const B& or const
>   volatile B&, and
>
> — for all the non-static data members of X that are
>   of a class type M (or array thereof), each such class type has a copy
>   constructor whose first parameter is of type const M& or const
>   volatile M&.
>
> *Otherwise*, *the implicitly-declared copy constructor will have the form*
>   `X::X(X&)`

I tried this by the following example:

```
struct B
{
    B(){ }
    B(const B&){}
};

struct A : B
{
    A(){ };
};

const A a;

A t = a; //OK Lvalue reference to const A can be initialized with 
         //an lvalue of const A.

int main(){ }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb48be2f6111b423)**

But if we remove the `class B` from the example as follows:

```
struct A
{
    A(){ };
};

const A a;

A t = a; //OK, Why?

int main(){ }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e29b0741fdf76fd3)**

it'll still work fine. But because of the copy-constructor should have the form `A::A(A&)`, I expected that compile-time would be occured. Actually, If we write the following code:

```
struct A
{
    A(){ };
    A(A&){ };
};

const A a;

A t = a; //error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'A'

int main(){ }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a75069015f5843dd)**

it'll work as I expect.

So is the second case a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implicitly declared copy constructor in both cases is of the form `A(const A &)`, since that's the first case in the list and none of the restrictions apply.

Comment: Why? The Standard said that _Otherwise, the implicitly-declared copy constructor will have the form  X::X(X&)_. What's wrong?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: We're not in the "otherwise" branch. We're in the primary branch. The "if" after the primary branch evaluates "true".

Comment: There are no any base-class or non-static data member in the second case. Why are we still in the default branch? Do you mean that _for any element from empty-set_ guarantee that?

Comment: Right now, all of my Porsches are fuelled up, all of my plantations have been harvested, and all my children are happy. And that's true despite me having no money, no land and no women. And I'm pretty sure that all of your pet tigers have been fed. (That's just what "for all" means: there does not exist a counterexample.)

Comment: One can reword it: The implicitly defined copy-ctors argument is a `const`-qualified reference to the class-type, iff all sub-objects copy-ctor (member and base) accepts a `const`-qualified reference, otherwise unqualified.

Comment: Indeed, implication with false premise is true. I've understood. Thank you.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: Well, kind of... it's more predicate that propositional logic, but it's really pretty common logic: To assert some property for every item in a collection means that you cannot find an item that doesn't have the property.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by T.C. [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728495/implicitly-declared-copy-constructor-for-classes-without-data-members-and-base-c#comment42046026_26728519) the requirements can be vacuously true - that is, there may be no base classes at all and the requirements from the first bullet are still met:

> — each direct or virtual base class `B` of `X` has a copy constructor
>   whose first parameter is of type `const B&` or `const volatile B&`,
>   and

If there is no direct or virtual base class then this condition evaluates as true - it isn't required that there is *at least* one base class that has an appropriate copy constructor, it is required that there is *no base class that does not meet the requirement*, i.e. has a copy constructor that is not of the given form. You may also reword the text if that makes it clearer:

> — If `X` has direct or virtual base classes, each direct or virtual base class `B` of `X` has a copy constructor whose first parameter is of type `const B&` or `const volatile B&`,
>   and